# Animate an OverlayItem when retrieving coordinates from a WebService

Tags: android, android-mapview, overlayitem

I'm using a webservice to follow a car position and i display the car position on a map with an Overlay item.
I'm able to refresh the position of the car by removing/adding the overlayItem, however i would like to animate it from the old coordinates to the new one ithout removing it from the map. Is it possible ?